# logger printing same statement random number of times or not at all

Tags: python, logging

I have python logger being defined in the global part of a python script like so:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(threadName)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'
logfile = app.config['CONTROLROOM_WORKER_LOG_PATH']
loghandler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(logfile, when='midnight', interval=1, backupCount=10, encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False)
fmt = logging.Formatter(FORMAT)
loghandler.setFormatter(fmt)
logger = logging.getLogger('controlroom_worker')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(loghandler)
```

However issues I'm facing are the following:

- Sometimes a logger statement *prior* to some logic is ignored (that is, not logged), even though the logic is executed. This behavior is amplified when a lot of stuff needs to be printed.
- 90% percent of the times, everything that is printed, is printed *twice*! Although I have seen a few cases where something is printed 3 times. Example logging:

```
2017-12-08 17:51:10,823 config_notifier INFO Done notifying changes.
2017-12-08 17:51:10,823 config_notifier INFO Done notifying changes.
2017-12-08 17:51:15,829 config_notifier INFO Notifying changes.
2017-12-08 17:51:15,829 config_notifier INFO Notifying changes.
2017-12-08 17:51:15,829 config_notifier INFO Notifying changes.
2017-12-08 17:51:15,943 config_notifier INFO Committed !!!
2017-12-08 17:51:15,943 config_notifier INFO Committed !!!
2017-12-08 17:51:15,943 config_notifier INFO Committed !!!
2017-12-08 17:51:15,943 config_notifier INFO Done notifying changes.
2017-12-08 17:51:15,943 config_notifier INFO Done notifying changes.
2017-12-08 17:51:20,949 config_notifier INFO Notifying changes.
2017-12-08 17:51:20,949 config_notifier INFO Notifying changes.
2017-12-08 17:51:21,052 config_notifier INFO Committed !!!
2017-12-08 17:51:21,052 config_notifier INFO Committed !!!
2017-12-08 17:51:21,052 config_notifier INFO Done notifying changes.
2017-12-08 17:51:21,052 config_notifier INFO Done notifying changes.
2017-12-08 17:51:21,052 config_notifier INFO Done notifying changes.
2017-12-08 17:51:26,057 config_notifier INFO Notifying changes.
2017-12-08 17:51:26,057 config_notifier INFO Notifying changes.
```

See how stuff is being printed twice or thrice?

Here's something interesting:

In addition to using the `logging` package, I also tried logging by simply writing to a file and writing to it whenever a log is needed:

```
manual_logger=open("manual_log.txt", "a+")
manual_logger.write("Some message here" + "\n")
```

This manual logger always writes each log statement just *once* (as is to be expected), but *also* suffers from some logs being completely missed out randomly:

```
Done notifying changes.
Notifying changes.
Committed !!!
Done notifying changes.
Notifying changes.
Committed !!!
Done notifying changes.
Notifying changes.
Committed !!!
Done notifying changes.
Notifying changes.
Committed !!!
```

How do I solve these issues? They're driving me mad.

Comment: be sure only one instance of log handler get configured, and as your handler will rotate file, you could try to find missing lines in other log files.

Answer (score 0):

Try ensuring that the logging configuration code is called *only* from a `if __name__ == '__main__':` clause in your main script, and nowhere else. In particular, it shouldn't be called just when a module is imported, only when it is run as a main script.